# Multiple files with same name in asset library

Tags: file-upload

Is it possible to configure an asset library such that it will allow many files with identical names to be uploaded?

Scenario: Multiple students upload an assignment video called Assignment.mp4 to the same Asset Library.

We've tried auto-renaming the files during upload but without success. [Rename MP4 video file on upload](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88411/rename-mp4-video-file-on-upload)

Comment: Or instead of renaming the file, you can create a new folder with Student's name and place the file inside the folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward: no, it's not possible.
It's just like asking if it's possible to store two files with the same name inside the same folder on the file system.

The only solution is to create a folder for each student and have them upload their file to this very folder; in this case, you can have multiple files with the same name, as they will reside in different folders inside the same library.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store files with same name. Either students will get an access denied error or they overwrite the files with the same name.